# Ezimporter, Hi-URLRewrite and xblog support in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: sitecore-client

With my sitecore 8.1 solution, i am using EZimporter, Xblog and HI-UrlRewrite modules from sitecore market place. I would like know that, does sitecore 9.3 provide any of the features like EZimporter, Xblog and HI-UrlRewrite  Out of the box.

Does any one explored this with sitecore 9.3. if it is provided by sitecore 9.3 then i am thinking to use the one provided by sitecore.

Thanks

Comment: This probably would have been better as a question on https://sitecore.chat.

Comment: I had to make some small minor changes on HI-URLRewrite for 9.3